# R Interactive Financial/Asset Candle Chart with Indicator

Tags: r, plot, finance, interactive

I am looking for an alternative way to display an Interactive candle charts (if any exists), that looks like this

[image]

Above is sample static hourly candle charts with its indicator, because it is static, it is less informative, no hover information included, I generate this chart using `quantmod` packages, with this simple snippets:

```
asset1%>%chartSeries(TA=\"addCCI();addRSI();addMFI();\")
```

Thankyou for any kind of leads!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `plotly:`

```r
library(quantmod)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

AAPL <- getSymbols("AAPL", src='yahoo', auto.assign = FALSE) %>% tail(60)

df <- data.frame(Date=index(AAPL),coredata(AAPL))

fig <- df %>% plot_ly(x = ~Date, type="candlestick",
                      open = ~AAPL.Open, close = ~AAPL.Close,
                      high = ~AAPL.High, low = ~AAPL.Low) 

fig %>% layout(title = "Basic Candlestick Chart")
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

##### Screenshot of output:

[image: example of plot]

See more examples [here](https://plotly.com/r/candlestick-charts/).